# How to connect android fone to laptop via router

Tags: ip, connection

I have a setup of Laptop, router and phone using IP address. I can access the router on laptop but I can't access the cellphone via IP and fine can't access laptop on IP. router is is managing dhcp. running Win 7. pleases assist.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please edit your post.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is very difficult to understand what you are describing in your post. Please take a few minutes to explain what the problem is, what you have done to try to resolve it and where you are stuck. Then ask a specific question. If you need help, read [ask] in the [help].

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Check your router settings - you are probably running guest or isolated network. That is your router allows phone and laptop to connect to the internet but blocks peer communications between devices connected to the router.